# How do I find values of a,b,c,d such that rank of the matrix is 2, where A?

Tags: matrices

A = $\begin{pmatrix}1&a&b&0\\ 0&c&d&1\\ 2&a&2b&0\\ 0&2c&d&2\end{pmatrix} $

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please put the question within the body, not just in the title. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Are you looking for all solutions or only for one? In the first case, it would be relevant from which set you are allowed to take $a,b,c,d$ (e.g. integers, reals, etc.), in the second case $a=b=c=d=0$ should do the job.

Comment: The rank of a matrix is the number of vectors in the maximal linearly independent set of columns, so this question boils down to finding the values of $a, b, c$ and $d$ such that there are two linearly independent columns. You can do this by looking at the columns they have already given you and seeing what values you need to choose such that the two middle ones are not linearly independent of the outer two.

Comment: @DirkLiebhold But in general, $a=d=0$ will work.